# Setting Opacity Dynamically in fill-opacity

Tags: api, fill, react, transparency-opacity

I am trying to use a map I made in Mapbox Studio and data I have locally in js code to change the opacity on different countries on a map.

In my `dataLayer`, I define the layer as such:

```
    const dataLayer = {
    'id': 'countries',
    'source': {
      'type': 'vector',
      'url': 'mapbox://url'
    },
    'source-layer': 'layer name',
    'type': 'fill',
    'paint': {
      'fill-color': '#FF0000',
      'fill-opacity':['+', 0, ['number', ['in', 'ADM0_A3_IS'].concat(result).map(x => getOpacity(x)/2) .2]]
    },
    'filter': ['in', 'ADM0_A3_IS'].concat(result)
  };
```

In the fill opacity param, I call an `in` command in the mapbox API to get country codes ('USA') and then compare them to a list I have stored in code.

My goal is to use the list of country codes to get the opacity values, which I calculate in JS code. The `getOpacity()` method converts a country code to a float opacity value [0,1].

Maybe I am not understanding the docs right. How can I map the country code values to opacity, if the opacity data is not stored in Mapbox itself?